# How my Model Class should looks like for a retrofit request in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, request, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to create a request using Retrofit2 in Kotlin and my Json data looks like this:

```
{
  "actionRights": [
    {
      "hasArticlePriceChangeRights": false,
      "hasStockLevelViewRights": false
    }
  ],
  "stats": {
    "errors": 12,
    "warnings": 21,
    "outOfOrder": 58,
    "running": 42
  },
  "markers": []
}
```

I need to get the "stats" data from my response.

How is my model class look like? I tried something but I get this error.

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

**EDIT: I created this ModelClass and I'm still getting this error:
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $**

```
data class StatsModel(
        @SerializedName("actionRights") val actionRights : List<ActionRights>,
        @SerializedName("stats") val stats : Stats,
        @SerializedName("markers") val markers : List<Markers>
) {
    data class ActionRights (

            @SerializedName("hasArticlePriceChangeRights") val hasArticlePriceChangeRights : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("hasStockLevelViewRights") val hasStockLevelViewRights : Boolean
    )


    data class Stats (

            @SerializedName("errors") val errors : Int,
            @SerializedName("warnings") val warnings : Int,
            @SerializedName("outOfOrder") val outOfOrder : Int,
            @SerializedName("running") val running : Int
    )

    data class Markers (

            @SerializedName("deviceGuid") val deviceGuid : String,
            @SerializedName("lat") val lat : Double,
            @SerializedName("lng") val lng : Double,
            @SerializedName("title") val title : Int,
            @SerializedName("city") val city : String,
            @SerializedName("street") val street : Int,
            @SerializedName("serialNumber") val serialNumber : Int,
            @SerializedName("LastStatusMessageDateTime") val lastStatusMessageDateTime : String,
            @SerializedName("LastStatusMessageBitSet_0_63") val lastStatusMessageBitSet_0_63 : Int,
            @SerializedName("LastStatusMessageBitSet_64_127") val lastStatusMessageBitSet_64_127 : Int,
            @SerializedName("ActionsStatus") val actionsStatus : Int,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn1") val spareColumn1 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn2") val spareColumn2 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn3") val spareColumn3 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn4") val spareColumn4 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn5") val spareColumn5 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn6") val spareColumn6 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn7") val spareColumn7 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn8") val spareColumn8 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn9") val spareColumn9 : String,
            @SerializedName("SpareColumn10") val spareColumn10 : String,
            @SerializedName("EstimatedDeliveryDateTime") val estimatedDeliveryDateTime : String,
            @SerializedName("IpAddress") val ipAddress : String,
            @SerializedName("Active") val active : Int,
            @SerializedName("ParentAreaGuid") val parentAreaGuid : String,
            @SerializedName("AreaGuid") val areaGuid : String,
            @SerializedName("TariffGroupGuid") val tariffGroupGuid : String,
            @SerializedName("DeviceType") val deviceType : String,
            @SerializedName("EstimateArticleName") val estimateArticleName : String,
            @SerializedName("EstimateArticleGuid") val estimateArticleGuid : String,
            @SerializedName("lastCoinboxExchange") val lastCoinboxExchange : String,
            @SerializedName("lastStatusUpdateTime") val lastStatusUpdateTime : String,
            @SerializedName("reportDateTime") val reportDateTime : String,
            @SerializedName("hasFinancialInfo") val hasFinancialInfo : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("ticketsSold") val ticketsSold : Int,
            @SerializedName("cash") val cash : Int,
            @SerializedName("cashless") val cashless : Int,
            @SerializedName("hasStockLevel") val hasStockLevel : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("hasArticlePrices") val hasArticlePrices : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("EstDeliveryDays") val estDeliveryDays : String,
            @SerializedName("hasOther") val hasOther : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("hasOutOfOrder") val hasOutOfOrder : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("hasWarning") val hasWarning : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("hasError") val hasError : Boolean,
            @SerializedName("flags") val flags : List<Flags>,
            @SerializedName("actionState") val actionState : String,
            @SerializedName("spareColumns") val spareColumns : List<SpareColumns>
    )
    data class Flags (

            @SerializedName("ErrorLevel") val errorLevel : Int,
            @SerializedName("ErrorFlag") val errorFlag : Int,
            @SerializedName("Translation") val translation : String,
            @SerializedName("BitPosition") val bitPosition : Int
    )
    data class SpareColumns (

            @SerializedName("key") val key : String,
            @SerializedName("value") val value : String
    )
}
```

**And I'm processing the response like this:**

```
fun getStatusService(mandatorGuid: String, @Nullable statusCallbacks: ChartsCallbacks.StatsCallbacks) {
        val mandatorItem = MandatorItem(mandatorGuid)
        val guid: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        guid["guid"] = mandatorItem.guid
        var statusData: StatsModel.Stats

        val call: Call<StatsModel> = createAPI().getStatus(mandatorItem.guid)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<StatsModel> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<StatsModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("TEST", "Status failure: $t")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<StatsModel>, response: Response<StatsModel>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.i("TEST", "ITEM " + response.headers().toString())
                        statusData = response.body()!!.stats
                        Log.i("TEST", "ITEM $statusData")
                        statusCallbacks.onSuccess(statusData)

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: can you please show me your full response

Comment: This is my full Json:  http://www.jsonparser.xyz/show_original.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 data class ActionRight(
val hasArticlePriceChangeRights: Boolean?=null,
val hasStockLevelViewRights: Boolean?=null
 )
```

this is for state

```
   data class Stats(
    val errors:Int? = null,
    val warnings? = null,
    val outOfOrder? = null,
    val running? = null
    )
```

call this model into your retrofit you got only your state

```
data class StatsModel(
val actionRights: ArrrayList<ActionRight>?=null,
val markers: ArrrayList<Any>?=null,
val stats: Stats? = null)
```

Comment: Can you please review my question? I added some updates. Thanks

Comment: try this one its worked now and if not working than please show me your error

Comment: Status failure: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $. This is the error I'm getting..

Comment: This is my Json: https://jsonblob.com/d7b06b4c-2e4b-11eb-967c-5704a225d894

Comment: This is my JSON: https://jsonblob.com/d7b06b4c-2e4b-11eb-967c-5704a225d894

Answer (score 0):

**Your main model:**

```kotlin
data class MyModel(
    val actionRights: List<ActionRight?>?,
    val markers: List<Marker?>?,
    val stats: Stats?
)
```

**Your Sub Models:**

```kotlin
data class ActionRight(
    val hasArticlePriceChangeRights: Boolean?,
    val hasStockLevelViewRights: Boolean?
)
```

```kotlin
data class Marker(
    val test1: Int?,
    val test2: String?
)
```

```kotlin
data class Stats(
    val errors: Int?,
    val outOfOrder: Int?,
    val running: Int?,
    val warnings: Int?
)
```

I create a fake Marker class because I don't know your full json data.

You should modelling Marker class for according your json data. You can call `MyModel` class from retrofit.

**Edit Response (Only parse Stats class)**

This class represent parse only Stats class, you can call from retrofit. `@JsonIgnoreProperties` should ignore other data.

```kotlin
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class MyModel(
    @JsonProperty("stats")
    val stats: Stats?
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Stats(
    @JsonProperty("errors")
    val errors: Int?,
    @JsonProperty("outOfOrder")
    val outOfOrder: Int?,
    @JsonProperty("running")
    val running: Int?,
    @JsonProperty("warnings")
    val warnings: Int?
)
```

**Note:** The code use Jackson library.

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.5.0'`

Comment: But can I create MyModel class only with the stats : Stats field? Or it must contains all fields from the json data?

Comment: I updated my question, can you please review it? Thanks!

Comment: Which json parser use on your project? As I understand you need only stats data. It is possible but I don't sure this is right way. You need ignore property in json. For example if you use `Jackson` library, you can try `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation. If you need this I can update the my response.

Comment: But I dont know why I'm getting that error if my ModelClass is exactly as the Json response..

Comment: Do you need parse all json data or only part of Stats? I will help you for your need

Comment: I need only Stats data

Comment: I tried this, but still having the same error. But if I change the response to List<StatsModel> instead of StatsModel, it's working with the code from the question. But when I access response.body().stats I'm receiving a null list..

Comment: Your json data should be different if it is working change to List<Stats>. Null list problem is different, maybe it caused by something else.

Comment: I know that my json data should be different but as it is now, it's working with List<StatsModel>.. but now I have the null list problem

Comment: can you share your json data?

Comment: https://jsonblob.com/d7b06b4c-2e4b-11eb-967c-5704a225d894

Comment: I test it with your json data, it's working good with me. I didn't wrapper `Stats` with `List`. I test convert string to json. I think something wrong with your json data or retrofit implemention. Did you check your http response is same that share json data ?

Comment: I found the problem, and solved it! Thank you for your time and help!